# Scapy: how to match queries and answers

Tags: python, networking, protocols, scapy

I'm implementing a protocol in Scapy, and here is what I've done far (details omitted):

```
class Protocol - #Defines some common headers
    def guess_payload_class:
        return ProtocolAction1

class ProtocolAction1 - #Defines some action to be done by the protocol.


class ProtocolAnswer - #Defines some common headers
    def guess_payload_class:
        return ProtocolAction1Anser

class ProtocolAction1Answer - #Defines the answer when Action1 has been done.

bind_layers(UDP, Protocol, dport=port)
bind_layers(UDP, ProtocolAnswer, sport=port)
```

However, when I do an `sr(IP()/UDP()/Protocol()/ProtocolAction1())`, I can never get an answer (although the server sends it). My intention is to get an `IP()/UDP()/ProtocolAnswer()/ProtocolAction1Answer()`. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you reviewed the relevant Scapy information? http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/build_dissect.html

Comment: Yes, I've read that, but it seems that I don't fully understand it. If for example I do:

    sr(Protocol())

I can see how the function guess_payload_class from ProtocolAnswer is executed, but it never stops. For example:

    Begin emission:
    ..Finished to send 1 packets.
    answer
    ........................................

Where answer is a trace written in ProtocolAnswer.guess_payload_class

Comment: If I do a paralell sniff, I can see that it identifies correctly the packet as an answer. But the main problem continues: when doing a call to sr(), it never stops because it never identifies the packet as a ProtocolAction1Answer